# Problems with Apple Push Notification Service and multiple servers

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

We are developing an iOS app we want to receive push notifications, and we have two different server-side environments with different IP but both of them have the same APNs production certificate. From one of this servers, the push notifications are received in the devices, but not from the other one. The implementation on servers regarding APNS is the same in both environments, and ports stated by Apple to communicate with APNS are reachable from both.

I can't figure out what is happening, can the same APNs production certificate being used from several servers in different networks? Are we missing anything else? Is there any way to see if the server is properly communicating with APNS, and what is doing APNS with our push requests?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your web services written by PHP team?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question :- Yes, you can use same APNS certificate with multiple servers & that too in different networks.

For second question:- Not sure, but problem might be with port. You should cross-check your server code.

Comment: Apple returns errors if you listen for them. I personally tested two different push servers same cert and it works just fine.